# Blob images are not pushed to an array in the right order

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, html5-canvas

I have function toBlobConverter which is sent to a for loop to cut an image into 9 pieces but the images are not arranged in right order. Happy to hear from you.

```
const toBlobConverter = async (x, y) => {
  var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  canvas.width = widthOfOnePiece;
  canvas.height = heightOfOnePiece;
  var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  context.drawImage(
    image,
    y * widthOfOnePiece,
    x * heightOfOnePiece,
    widthOfOnePiece,
    heightOfOnePiece,
    0,
    0,
    canvas.width,
    canvas.height
  );
  async function operation() {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      canvas.toBlob(resolve);
    });
  }
  const compOperation = await operation();
  console.log(compOperation);
  return imagePieces.push({
    url: URL.createObjectURL(compOperation),
    blob: compOperation,
  });
}
for (var x = 0; x < 3; ++x) {
  for (var y = 0; y < 3; ++y) {
    toBlobConverter(x, y)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, the asynchronous operations are in a race with each other. They're all **started** one after another by your `for` loops, and then they complete in whatever order they complete in, which is what determines where they end up in the array. Nothing waits for `toBlobConverter` to finish its asynchronous work.

If you want them to do their work in parallel, you can use `Promise.all` to get the results in the order you asked for them. That will require reorganizing your code *slightly* but arguably for the better since it doesn't require `toBlobConverter` to "magically" fill in `imagePieces`; see the `***` comments:

```
const toBlobConverter = async (x, y) => {
  var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  canvas.width = widthOfOnePiece;
  canvas.height = heightOfOnePiece;
  var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  context.drawImage(
    image,
    y * widthOfOnePiece,
    x * heightOfOnePiece,
    widthOfOnePiece,
    heightOfOnePiece,
    0,
    0,
    canvas.width,
    canvas.height
  );
  async function operation() {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      canvas.toBlob(resolve);
    });
  }
  const compOperation = await operation();
  console.log(compOperation);
  // *** Return the entry rather than pushing it
  return {
    url: URL.createObjectURL(compOperation),
    blob: compOperation,
  };
}

// *** Build an array of the promises in the  order you want
const promises = [];
for (var x = 0; x < 3; ++x) {
  for (var y = 0; y < 3; ++y) {
    promises.push(toBlobConverter(x, y));
  }
}

// *** Wait for the operations to complete
Promise.all(promises)
.then(results => {
    // *** `results` is in the same order `promises` was
    imagePieces.push(...results);
})
.catch(error => {
    // Handle/report errors
});
```

If you want them done one after another (in *series*), just put your `for` loops in an `async` function and `await` the result of `toBlobConverter`:

```
(async () => {
    for (var x = 0; x < 3; ++x) {
      for (var y = 0; y < 3; ++y) {
        await toBlobConverter(x, y)
      }
    }
})()
.catch(error => {
    // Handle errors...
});
```

---

For what it's worth, when writing modern code, I strongly recommend not using `var`. Anywhere. :-) Use `let` or `const`.